# Stargazing with the Ancients

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, geography, science

[image: Stargazing with the Ancients]

Clues: [contextual images]
Instructions: Name That Landmark

_ _ _ N _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The landmark you are looking for is

> **MOUNT VESUVIUS**!

---

The grid is actually

> The planets of the solar system represented using chemical elements. The first is a bit of wordplay with using the element Mercury - Hg, while the rest are made up as follows, removing letters where necessary:
>
>  [image]
>
> And as you can see, following the arrows spells out 'VESUVIUS' - the name of the landmark we are after!

> OP Edit - Additionally, the chemical number for Mercury is 80. the phrase "80-1=explosion" is meant to point to the year 79AD when Vesuvius erupted. Furthermore, during the time period of 79AD, the only known planets were Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn.

Comment: What was the thought process to put the elements in the places as you did?

Comment: @justhalf I realised quite quickly it was planets from mercury, stargazing, and neptune at the bottom, and I think there is actually only one way to make each of the planets from element names given the restrictions, so it was actually very easy to make the names!

Comment: Ah, ok. So basically from Mercury (space/planet hinted by stargazing), you extrapolated all the planet names and try to put elements that build up to the names? got it

Comment: @justhalf pretty much, I also knew the planet names were in order as mercury was at the top so just had to find elements that fitted with the minus letter clues, the 85 = At clue, and the right amount of boxes, which was fairly simple to do with a list of elements